# TypeError: Cannot read property 'activities' of null

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

My problem is that when the user starts a game and has the game status in discord, on the console I get the error "TypeError: Unable to read property 'activities' of null"
I hope the bot gives the member a role when starting the game. I'm using a game as an example, I need the function when starting the stream
Discord.js - v13 Code:

```js
const client = require('../index')

client.on('presenceUpdate', function(oldMember, newMember) {
    const guild = newMember.guild;
    const streamingRole = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Fazendo Live');

    // if (newMember.user.bot || newMember.presence.clientStatus === 'mobile' || oldMember.status !== newMember.status) return;

    const oldGame = oldMember.activities ? oldMember.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'PLAYING') : false;
    const newGame = newMember.activities ? newMember.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'PLAYING') : false;

    if (!oldGame && newGame) {         // Started playing.
      newMember.member.roles.add(streamingRole)
        .then(() => console.log(`${streamingRole.name} added to ${newMember.user.tag}.`))
        .catch(console.error);
    } 

    else if (oldGame && !newGame) {  // Stopped playing.
      newMember.member.roles.remove(streamingRole)
        .then(() => console.log(`${streamingRole.name} removed from ${newMember.user.tag}.`))
        .catch(console.error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Discord V13 requires the presence intent to be included, have you included it in your client?

Comment: Yes, I included it in my client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`member.activities` is not a thing. You need to go through `presence` first to go through activities.

```js
const oldGame = oldMember.presence.activities ? oldMember.presence.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'PLAYING') : false;
const newGame = newMember.presence.activities ? newMember.presence.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'PLAYING') : false;
```

**Did more digging...**

...and found out that `presenceUpdate` actually outputs old and new presences and not the member. So in that way you are correct with

```js
const oldGame = oldMember.activities
```

Now while doing my own testings I came across that when trying simply doing `message.member.presence` and console logging that, it comes out as null, and this is because I had no Intents set to my client for `GUILD_PRESENCES` now when I enabled this, it showed me the activity.

So my guess is that if you are getting null from it, or the error that `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'activities')` which I got aswell (before declaring intents), you might be setting your intents wrong.

Are you sure you have declared your intents correctly in `index.js`?

Mine for example:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES]
});
```

Comment: Don't work but I tried this:

```
const oldStream = oldMember.member.presence.activities ? oldMember.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'PLAYING') : false;
    const newStream = newMember.member.presence.activities ? newMember.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'PLAYING') : false;
```
Send me that error: Cannot read property 'member' of null

Comment: What exactly did not work with above one? Yours did not work because member.member is not a thing either.

Comment: That's why the code above is not working:
```Cannot read property 'activities' of undefined```

When I added Member before Presence it worked BUT it gives the error of my previous comment

Comment: I did more digging and edited my own answer for you, hope it helps @OtávioQuirino

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but I believe the error is from Discord itself. The error ```Cannot read property 'activities' of null``` only happens on the "oldMember" line